# To me/For me Which one?

Tags: grammar

Could somebody please  tell me that which sentence is correct?

**To me**, Italy is the best place to go on vacation.

**For me**, Italy is the best place to go on vacation.

Comment: I'm not that fond of either one. I'd say, "**In my opinion**, Italy the best place to go on vacation." But I don't think these are wrong; there's a valid question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the sentence

> To me, Italy is the best place to to go on vacation.

you are just telling your opinion but not experienced.

but when you use *for*  it specifies that you have done it and telling your opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree; that is, I don't think that _to_ implies it's just a notion, while _for_ implies first-hand experience.

Comment: @J.R. agreed. If it were "it seems to me", that would definitely be opinion...